# Divide integer elements in an array

Tags: java, arrays, math

How do you divide all the input integers in an array?
I have this method called division. It only gets the sum of the integers I've input. How do divide them?

```
public class Arithmetic {
public int division(int[] n) {
    int quotient = 0;
    for (int num : n) {
        quotient = quotient / num;
    }
    return sum;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Arithmetic a = new Arithmetic();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("1: Division");
    System.out.print("Enter selection here: ");
    int choice = sc.nextInt();
    switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            System.out.print("Enter no. of elements you want in array: ");
            int numOfElements = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter elements in the array ~ ");
            if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
                int arraysInput[] = new int[numOfElements];
                for (int i = 0; i < numOfElements; i++) {
                    arraysInput[i] = sc.nextInt();
                }
                System.out.println("Quotient: " + a.division(arraysInput));
            }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to divide them with?

Comment: any integer that user inputs. It ask for number of elements in array and then it asks for the elements or the intergers that i want to divide up with like ex. The user inputs 3 elements -  10 / 5 / 1 = 2

Comment: There is syntax error as well. Where is the variable sum declared ? there is no {} for switch statement

Comment: I forgot to paste some of it, I'm just having problems on my for loop in division method. On how do you divide the numbers that the user inputs..

Comment: I have added an answer below and edited the question for you, it will will be updated soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your division method with this

```
public int division(int[] n) {
    int quotient = n[0] ;
    for (int i = 1; i < n.length ; i++) {
        quotient = quotient / n[i];
    }
    return quotient;
}
```

The whole class looks like with some test code :

```
public class Arithmetic {

    public int division(int[] n) {
        int quotient = n[0] ;
        for (int i = 1; i < n.length ; i++) {
            quotient = quotient / n[i];
        }
        return quotient;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Arithmetic a = new Arithmetic();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        
        // Test Division
        // System.out.println( "Divison of {10,5,1} : " + a.division(new int[]{10,5,1}));


        System.out.println("1: Division");
        System.out.print("Enter selection here: ");
        int choice = sc.nextInt();
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                System.out.print("Enter no. of elements you want in array: ");
                int numOfElements = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter elements in the array ~ ");
                if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
                    int arraysInput[] = new int[numOfElements];
                    for (int i = 0; i < numOfElements; i++) {
                        arraysInput[i] = sc.nextInt();
                    }
                    System.out.println("Quotient: " + a.division(arraysInput));
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer will not work. Unfortunately I don't have enough "rep" to post comments.

for reference:

```
public int division(int[] n) {
int quotient = n[0] ;
for (int i = 1; i < n.length ; i++) {
    quotient = quotient / n[i];
}
return quotient;
```

}

1. if the array of values is empty or null - exception thrown.
2. if the array contains a zero (DivisionByZeroException)
3. if the array has only one value, the returned value is not the quotient (unless the assumption is value/1?)
4. - nitpicking... but shouldn't the return be a double or a float?